# Probability - Chocolate Distribution Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Ten chocolates are distributed randomly among three children standing in a row. The probability that the first child receives exactly three chocolates?**

My approach:
Sample Space |S| = $3^{10}$ as each chocolate can be given in 3 ways.

We can select 1 child out of 3 children C(3,1) = 3 ways.
Select the child and give 3 chocolates to him, now we need to find the way we can distribute 7 chocolates to 2 children.

> X+Y = 7, using the formula C(n+r-1,r) = C(2+7-1,7) = 8 ways.
>
> So, the required probability will be $\frac{3*8}{3^{10}}$

Don't know, where am i making the mistake?

Comment: Hint: binomial distribution. Every chocolate has a probability of $1/3$ to be given to the first child. What is the probability for $x\sim B(10,1/3)$ to take the value $x=3$?

Comment: In such problems, you want to be precise with your assumptions. For example, are the chocolates distinguishable? Note that with your original sample space $\mid S\mid$, you have implicitly assumed that they are in fact, distinguishable. Also note that you aren't supposed to *choose* a child

Comment: @ZhuoranHe thank you! i got the answer!

Comment: What, precisely, does it mean for 10 chocolates to be "distributed randomly" among three children? I don't think an "answer" to this question is meaningful until the question itself is clarified. [I would interpret this as, most likely, meaning that two children get 3 chocolates and one child gets four, but we randomize the lucky child.]